# How to combine BETWEEN with TIMESTAMPDIFF using PDO query?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to modify my existing code that returns from DB the rows that are between a specific date and time. It does the job right, but I would like to add a feature as described below.

This is an example of my DB

```
           start                  end
1st row    2012-07-24 18:00:00    2012-07-28 17:00:00
2nd row    2012-07-25 19:00:00    2012-07-30 19:00:00
3rd row    2012-07-25 22:00:00    2012-07-28 13:00:00
4th row    2012-07-25 23:40:00    2012-07-27 18:00:00
...
...
...
```

When my input is **2012-07-25 23:00:00** `BETWEEN start AND end ORDER by start DESC`

So the results are,

```
3rd row
2nd row
1st row
```

Until here everything is great. However, I want to list any rows that **are going to begin** in the next 2 hours at the top of the list.
*This is row number 4.*

I tried to do it using

```
 ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , `start`, :time )) < 2
```

unfortunately, I can't find the solution.

Below is my code since now, any help is appreciated. ( I use 3 variables, `selected`, `city` and `type`)

```
// Store where clauses and values in arrays
$values = $where = array();

if (!empty($selected)) { // 
    $where[] = ':selected BETWEEN `start` AND `end`';
    $values[':selected'] = $selected;
}

if (!empty($city)) { // 
    $where[] = '`city` = :city';
    $values[':city'] = $city;
}

if (!empty($type)) { // 
$where[] = '`type` = :type';
$values[':type'] = $type;
}

// Build query
$question = 'SELECT * FROM `events`';
if (!empty($where)) {
    $question .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);
    $question .= ' ORDER BY `start` DESC';
}

$query = $db->prepare($question);

$query->execute($values);
```

Comment: Haven't you asked this question before?

Comment: What RDBMS, SQL Server (based on `TIMESTAMPDIFF`)?  Don't use `BETWEEN` - always explicitly specify ranges (especially timestamp ranges) as 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive', which is what you're (most likely) storing anyways.  You're going to need to adjust what your starting range is, which would be something on the order of `WHERE startDate >= :inputStartDate + 2 HOURS`

Comment: @X-Zero I am using mySQL for the question above

Comment: @X-Zero But with what you are proposing `WHERE startDate >= :inputStartDate + 2 HOURS` I will show all the rows even though that they may ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check the order of your arguments, so I got the condition backwards.  However, my initial statement still stands.  Basically, the simplest answer is to adjust your starting time, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TMP
WHERE startedAt < DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2012-07-25 23:00:00'), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
AND endedBy >= TIMESTAMP('2012-07-25 23:00:00')
ORDER BY startedAt DESC
```

And have a working [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17ba6/28).

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I have implemented it right. Please tell me why should I not use BETWEEN and use `<=` instead? Does it have anything on performance ?

Comment: There is no performance difference, because `BETWEEN` is implicitly translated to (in most RDBMSs) an inclusive range (that is - `:input BETWEEN startedAt AND endedBy` -> `:input >= startedAt AND :input <= endedBy`).  The problem with inclusive ranges is that they inherently generate 'fencepost' (off-by-one) errors.  These are most pervasive with things like timestamps, where the difference is one millisecond (or less).  Attempting to set this for an inclusive range is difficult (moreso in SQL Server) - this is why iteration over arrays is usually done to `i < array.length`, in other languages

Comment: ...And of course I mentioned fence-post errors, while blithely committing them.

Answer (score 1):

You need a OR for the event start in next two hours.
for example

```
where type = :type and city = :city and
((:selected BETWEEN `start` AND `end`) or 
 (`start` between :selected and adddate(:selected, interval 2 hours))
)
order by `start` desc
```

Comment: Ok I found where the mistake is. Thanks.

Comment: Please tell me, the user X-ZERO who posted a solution says that it's better not to use BETWEEN for these kind of things. What is your opinion about this ?

Comment: the solution propose by him is no different from using between. range query (between, or >=, <=) is less optimized because mysql require to find out what are the rows match the criteria, is like a multiple OR